# Visual Studio for Mac : AddIn Development

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a custom Project configuration wizard in Visual Studio (Mac) ([like this](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/xamarin-project-templates-for-visual-studio-for-mac.aspx)).

- Created the GUI with Xamarin Forms + GTK
- Started the Addin Developemnt (As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/extending-visual-studio-mac-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019))

But how can I introduce a new screen between the project configuration wizard, which contains custom configurations.

### Update

Now I am trying with this [link](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/project-templates/). But still I am trying to add Template Wizard. The configuration window is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointing wrong wizard id in the configuration file.

```
<Wizard>MyAddIn.GUI.MyConfigurationWizard</Wizard>
```